# Storing multiple column values into PHP array from MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I currently have an array that stores the values of one column from the database and that works fine however I want to store more than one column value. So in my example I want a team and their venue stored in the same array index. I can't seem find a way to do this.

If anyone can perhaps help that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please show us some code, SE is not a newspaper

Comment: Show us the code you've tried to use thus far

Comment: This is what I have so far.. `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

   $names[$loop]= $row['teamName']; 

  $loop++;
  

}`

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
$i = 0;
$my_array = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $my_array[$i]['name'] = $row['names'];
    $my_array[$i]['otherfield'] = $row['otherfield'];
    $i++;
}
```

now you can do something like this

```
echo $my_array[2]['name'];
```

Comment: That looks like what I want to do! I'm no longer at my computer at the moment but will test it when I get back to it. I appreciate your help with it this far!

Comment: No problem ;) I typed it here on the fly so beware of typos and syntax errors. But you should get the general idea. Oh and mysql_fetch_assoc is short for mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)

Comment: mysql_fetch_assoc is deprecated and you should be using mysqli_fetch_assoc

Answer (score 0):

Simply do :

```
$rows = [];
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: mysql_fetch_assoc is deprecated and you should be using mysqli_fetch_assoc